# BenchmarkDotNet InProcessEmitToolchain Complete Sample

Tags: c#, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I'm looking at BenchmarkDotNet and benchmarking in general for the first time ever. I appear to be unable to run benchmarks using the normal BenchmarkRunner because of antivirus restrictions on our work laptops so I'm trying to use InProcessEmitToolchain, as documented [here](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/toolchains.html#usage). However, in those samples and the ones listed [here](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/samples/IntroInProcess.html) I see no entry point for the application that will actually trigger the benchmarks and I've gotten nowhere useful reading through the documentation.

Can anyone point me at a complete sample of how to use the InProcessEmitToolchain and/or jobs that explains how to use jobs in conjunction with an application entry point to run the tests?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was facing the same problem with antivirus (Windows Defender) blocking BenchmarkDotNet. I was able to figure out how to change the toolchain setup, though I had to use `InProcessNoEmitToolchain` since `InProcessEmitToolchain` was also blocked.

The example below did not actually trigger the antivirus, but it shows how to define which toolchain to use:

**[Program.cs]**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using Benchmarks;

_ = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MaterializeTest>();
```

**[MaterializeTest.cs]**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

namespace Benchmarks;

[Config(typeof(AntiVirusFriendlyConfig))]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class MaterializeTest
{
    IEnumerable<int> _sequence;

    [Params(10, 100, 1000, 10000)]
    public int _size;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, _size).Select(i => Random.Shared.Next());
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public IReadOnlyList<int> ToList() => _sequence.ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public IReadOnlyList<int> ToArray() => _sequence.ToArray();
}
```

**[AntiVirusFriendlyConfig.cs]**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Configs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Toolchains.InProcess.NoEmit;

namespace Benchmarks;

public class AntiVirusFriendlyConfig : ManualConfig
{
    public AntiVirusFriendlyConfig()
    {
        AddJob(Job.MediumRun
            .WithToolchain(InProcessNoEmitToolchain.Instance));
    }
}
```

**[Benchmarks.csproj]**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.13.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm not the OP but this gave me the information I needed to solve the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me either.

Answer (score 6):

You can tweak the configuration with the toolchains you like:

```
var config = DefaultConfig.Instance
    .AddJob(Job
         .MediumRun
         .WithLaunchCount(1)
         .WithToolchain(InProcessEmitToolchain.Instance));
```

Or alternatively

```
var config = DefaultConfig.Instance
    .AddJob(Job
         .MediumRun
         .WithLaunchCount(1)
         .WithToolchain(InProcessNoEmitToolchain.Instance));
```

And pass it to the Run method (building on the program from [Andreas Warberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74078463/1399018))

```
_ = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MaterializeTest>(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up being unable to solve this even using the InProcesNoEmitToolchain - our AV software was too persistent. I solved it by getting our IT folks to give us a folder whitelist entry in the AV software where we could run benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where the app components being benchmarked was simply too slow; to circumvent this issue (the error message was `takes too long to run. Prefer to use out-of-process toolchains for long-running benchmarks`), I used the guidance given by other answers above, and extended it to the following:

```
public class MediumConfig : ManualConfig
{
    public MediumConfig()
    {
        AddJob(
               Job.MediumRun
                  .WithToolchain(InProcessNoEmitToolchain.Instance)
                  .WithStrategy(BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.RunStrategy.Throughput)
              )
            .WithOptions(ConfigOptions.DisableOptimizationsValidator);
    }
}
```

The config is then applied as usual:

```
[Config(typeof(MediumConfig))]
public class MyBenchmarkClassThatComparesALongRunningSetOfThings
{
    // ...
}
```